# Bootstrap not working correctly with meteor

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am using meteor and Bootstrap via twbs:bootstrap version 3.3.6, and the padding/margins are not as they are supposed to :

I even copy-pasted the code given by bootstrap for [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/) navbar for testing, and what I am getting instead is : [This skewed version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tClF.png).

I.e the padding between the navbar and the individual links are off and things are not centered.

I am  also getting similar problems to several other places, for instance text fields in forms are "squeezed" to the point that letters are cut off!

I have found several threads about problems with twbs:bootstrap and meteor, however most of them are very old (2012-13) and do not provide a solution to this issue.

My questions then are:

- Any ideas why this is happening?
- Are there any fixes, workarounds ?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

In order to **reproduce the error** in under 5 minutes:

- create a new meteor project : `meteor create BootstrapTest`
- Delete all the files under `client/` and `server/`
- Install packages : replace the contents of `.meteor/packages` by:

  meteor-base
  mobile-experience
  mongo
  blaze-html-templates
  reactive-var
  jquery
  tracker

  standard-minifier-css
  standard-minifier-js
  es5-shim
  ecmascript

  autopublish
  insecure
  iron:router

  session

  bootstrap

  ethereum:web3

  sacha:spin

  aldeed:collection2

  twbs:bootstrap

  aldeed:autoform

  underscore
- create a folder `lib/` and a file `lib/router.js` at the very top lever.
- put the following code in `lib/router.js` :

  Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate:'layout'
  });
- create a file `client/testcss.css` with the following code:`body { padding-top: 70px; }`
- create a file `client/layout.html` with the following code:

  ```
  <template name="layout"><nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">

      <div class="starter-template">
          <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
          <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>

  </div></template>
  ```
- Run the application by running `$meteor` in the application's folder.

Comment: This is a really great question. Sublime!!

Comment: Are you using any other view-related packages? This may be related to box-sizing. Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks for advice, I updated the question with the details of how to quickly recreate the error !

Comment: Have you checked the CSS in the Dev Tools to see what's being applied and where it is coming from?

Comment: Why are you both the (flagged) `bootstrap` and `twbs:bootstrap` packages? In addition, a git repo would have been much simpler as a reproduction.

Comment: @MasterAM Good spot, that was actually the issue:I had not noticed there was the two bootstrap packages! By deleting the ```bootstrap``` package it worked. This came probably along with some other package as a bundle. If you want to answer this I will endorse it as the answer. Good point for the git repo, apologies, I'll do that next time. Thanks!

Comment: Done. This can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the package listing in the question, you added both the (deprecated) `bootstrap` and `twbs:bootstrap` packages.

Remove the `bootstrap` package to resolve the issue.

You can also add bootstrap directly from npm, without using any meteor-specific package.

In general, you can use the browser's developer tools to see where each style rule originates, which can assist you in detecting the source of the problem.